# I can't launch FastqCleaner I always get a warning message and the application never starts

Tags: r, bioconductor, fastq, rstudio

I tried to install all the needed and related packages but I still did not know what the problem is, Can anyone please help if anything else I can do??
I always get this over and over:

```
Warning: Error in : Navigation containers expect a collection of `bslib::nav()`/`shiny::tabPanel()`s and/or `bslib::nav_menu()`/`shiny::navbarMenu()`s. Consider using `header` or `footer` if you wish to place content above (or below) every panel's contents.
  85: stop
  84: FUN
  83: lapply
  82: buildTabset
  81: tabsetPanel_
  80: func
  78: tabsetPanel
```

Comment: This error message looks incomplete. It would help for you to post your exact workflow and the full output. Links to the tool/documentation that you used are also always helpful.